# Enable to use django-extensions with pygraphviz

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, graphviz

I'm trying to use *pygraphviz* under *Ubuntu 10.04* within my *Django* projects.

I used *synaptic* and it was installed without any problem.

I also installed *django-extensions* with *synaptic* (*django-extensions* has a tool that uses *pygraphviz* and this is the one that I need)

Now when I try to use *django-extensions* with *pygraphviz*

```
$ python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o model.png
```

I'm getting an

> Error: need pygraphviz python module ( apt-get install
>   python-pygraphviz )

How can I fix this ?

Comment: I have already [posted](http://superuser.com/questions/313278/pygraphviz-install-on-ubuntu-10-with-django-extensions) on superuser.com but seems like too technical :(not sure an admin knows what is Django)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was facing the same problem on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine and I solved it installing the missing packages as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz-dev
sudo pip install pygraphviz
```

Comment: In my case, `apt-get install python-pydot` was also necessary.

Answer (score 3):

On mac, I got same errors too. I was using a Virtualenv, but this shouldn't change the procedure.

This is what I did:

`brew install graphviz`

`pip install python-pygraphviz`

Now, I have installed pygraphviz from source.

May be you can do this too: `pip install pygraphviz`

and then when I did `python manage.py graph_models -a -o polls_models.png`, it worked.

Comment: you have to pass --install-option="--include-path=/usr/local/include/graphviz/" \
--install-option="--library-path=/usr/local/lib/graphviz"

as options to pip

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar issue. I was able to install `django-extensions` but pygraphviz was giving error.

To install pygraphviz I first installed the requirement using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install graphviz-dev
```

Then used the following command

**Python2**

```
sudo pip install pygraphviz
```

**Python3**

```
sudo pip3 install pygraphviz
```

After installing it globally I again installed it in virtual environment using

```
pip install pygraphviz   #---> python2
pip3 install pygraphviz  #---> python3
```

Answer (score 2):

Just install `python-pygraphviz` with synaptic the same way you did pygraphvis and django-extensions.

Comment: I tried complete removal and re-installation of those 2 packages, still have the same problem :(

Answer (score 1):

First I run
`$python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o model_vi.png`

But I get an error!
`Error: You need to install pygraphviz python module`

I tried this
`$sudo easy_install pygraphviz`

But again I get an error
`unable to install pygraphviz with easy_install`

Later I tried this;
`$brew install graphviz`

If you get an error in this section you try
`$brew doctor`

And then;

You can run the real command.
`$python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o model_vi.png`

It works fine. Hope yours work fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install python-pygraphviz
```

read the error...
i tried apt-get solution and works fine

you can also try with

```
sudo easy_install pygraphviz
```

(i suppose you have pip / easy_install on your computer)

Comment: no error with `apt-get install python-pygraphviz` (after uninstallation) `easy_install pygraphviz` gives my a `...Your Graphviz installation could not be found...`

Comment: with "read the error" i meant you have to read the error in your first post, you had the solution there... so? apt-get install fixed your problem? you don't have to use both solutions, apt-get OR easy_install

Comment: I know but I though maybe the error from easy_install could tell us something. I confirm that `apt-get install python-pygraphviz` doesn't fix the problem.